# reading configuration files

Tags: c, linux, performance, configuration-files

I need the most efficient (performance/speed wise) way for reading a configuration from a file in C under linux.

I have not decided on the config format yet, but I would prefer (I'm all ears for better formats) the following format:

```
buttons   3
size 100 
etc.
```

(The option name then the option value delimited by whitespace)

How can I read the options, should I go for `strcmp`? Or should I go for character by character manual comparison? Is there a more efficient way?

I want the program to:

- be as quick as possible (time)
- use as little cpu time as possible
- use as little memory as possible

This code will be written for Linux (generic)
So far I'm using: `xtest`, `stdio`, `stdlib` and `string` libraries

I would rather code everything myself than use external libraries (which are not part of most Linux distributions).

Comment: Reading configuration files is something that should only happen once per invocation of your program, so I don't imagine it would be any kind of bottleneck in terms of your program's performance. Besides, the method that provides optimal speed or performance depends entirely on the content of your configuration file, so your question is impossible to answer. I suggest you use [liblcfg](http://liblcfg.carnivore.it/) and then come back here if you can explain **clearly** why it doesn't meet your needs. In the meantime, I'm going to flag this question as "too broad".

Comment: Consider writing your config files in json and using cjson (which is very easy to work with), or if they aren't hand written, xml and libxml

Comment: The reason I cannot use external libraries is because it will be installed on the company laptop which does not allow external software/source code

Comment: This is not a programming question I'm afraid. It probably belongs on another network. Also please put some effort formatting your question.

Comment: Use `fgets`, `sscanf`, and `strcmp`.

Answer (score 1):

Write/Read binary data for performance.

```
struct config { /* whatever */ };

struct config config;
configread(&config, "configfile"); // fread() or read() or whatever()
configwrite(&config, "configfile"); // fwrite() or write() or whatever()
```

Comment: You might even pass a flag to the `configread`/`configwrite` functions and have them read/write binary data or text data ... then compare the differences and determine if you really need "the most efficient way"